# Setting Up Local Repository with TortoiseSVN in Windows

Tags: windows, svn, tortoise-svn

I'm trying to set up a local repository so that all commitments are copied to the local destination, not a remote server. I followed [this tutorial](http://yacoding.blogspot.jp/2008/03/how-to-use-tortoisesvn-to-create-local.html).

What I did.

1. Created a folder named "SVN_Repo" under C:\Documents and Settings[user-name]\My Documents\
2. Right clicked on the folder and chose `TortoiseSVN -> Create repository here`
3. Clicked `OK` in the pop up dialog asking whether to create a directory structure.
4. Created a folder named `Repos` for the local destination, under E:\
5. Right clicked on the `SVN_Repo` folder and chose `SVN Checkout...`
6. Typed `file:///E:\repos` in the `URL of repository` field and clicked the OK button.

   [image]
7. What I got:

   > Checkout from file:///E:/repos, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included
   >
   > Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///E:/repos'
   >
   > Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
   >
   > Unable to open repository 'file:///E:/repos'

   [image]

I must be doing something wrong. Could somebody point it out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page, https://stackoverflow.com/a/741664/1608619 *ollifant* (user) says,

> The "Create repository here" action creates a repository which you can access locally via file://.. syntax or via the svnserve daemon.
>
> The "Checkout" action can be done in any other place. You can either use a local repository, access a repository via http(s) or svnserve.

It seems I had to select `Create repository here...` for the destination folder. By doing this I've started getting no errors. And I could comit some files but the strange thing is that the destination folder does not have the exact same directory structure as the working directory.

To see if it is working, I created another directory and choose `SVN Checkout` from the context menu, and it surely synchronized the files with the other working directory previously created. So it seems it's working.

Answer (score 2):

Until step #4 you were doing OK.

Step 5 should be - Right click `Repos` folder and choose `SVN Checkout...`

Step 6 should be - Type `file:///C:\Documents and Settings[user-name]\My Documents\` in the URL of repository field and click the OK button.

Then you can copy files into your `Repos` folder (a better naming could be `SourceCode` folder) and check them in.